# jsf and page fragment caching

Tags: jsf, caching

Does jsf 2.0 + facelets supports page fragment caching, something similar to aps page framgent caching
(example this tutorial http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/caching/fragment.aspx)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The answer on your question actually depends on the view technology in question. JSF is a component based MVC framework, not a view technology. JSF usually runs on either [JSP](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/JSPIntro.html) or [Facelets](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/giepx.html) as view technology.

Both view technologies however doesn't provide an `OutputCache` like facility out of the box. You would need to create a custom tag/component for this. JBoss Seam has a similar component in the toolbox, the [`<s:cache>`](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.0.1.GA/reference/en/html/controls.html).